# Confused with signing android APK?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, apk, jks

I have followed the steps as per [officials](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html) says for digitally signing my android application.for signing in release mode they are saying to use `.keystore` file and it's credentials like [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode).I am using android studio so that am getting `.jks` file instead.So where do i need to keep the `.jks` file according to the [docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode) for building my signed APK ? Please give a simple elaboration on this.and say if am doing anything wrong ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can put the `.jks` file anywhere.
It means that you can put the file inside your project, or you can put the file in an external folder (just take a look the path below).
It depends by your policy.

Just use gradle to configure the signing of your apk.

```
android {

    signingConfigs {
        release
    }

    buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
    }
}
```

**Simple way:** just define the credential inside your build.gradle file.

```
signingConfigs {
     release {
            //Pay attention to the path. You can use a relative path or an absolute path
            storeFile file("../your_key_store_file.jks")
            storePassword 'some_password'
            keyAlias 'alias_name'
            keyPassword 'key_password'

     }
  }
```

**Using a .properties file** to store the credentials outside the script (for example if you don't want to push the credential in a git repo).

Example: `signing.properties`

```
STORE_FILE=/path/to/your.keystore
STORE_PASSWORD=yourkeystorepass
KEY_ALIAS=projectkeyalias
KEY_PASSWORD=keyaliaspassword
```

Then get these values in your build.gradle file:

```
signingConfigs {
        release
 }
```

Then define:

```
def Properties props = new Properties()
def propFile = new File('signing.properties')
if (propFile.canRead()){
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propFile))

    if (props!=null && props.containsKey('STORE_FILE') && props.containsKey('STORE_PASSWORD') &&
            props.containsKey('KEY_ALIAS') && props.containsKey('KEY_PASSWORD')) {
        android.signingConfigs.release.storeFile = file(props['STORE_FILE'])
        android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = props['STORE_PASSWORD']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = props['KEY_ALIAS']
        android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = props['KEY_PASSWORD']
    } else {
        println 'signing.properties found but some entries are missing'
        android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
    }
}else {
    println 'signing.properties not found'
    android.buildTypes.release.signingConfig = null
}
```

Comment: Which means we don't want to keep `.jks` file inside apk root ie app root ? Why we are giving these things `storeFile file("myreleasekey.keystore")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"`
 in gradle ? please elaborate the answer for my doubt.

Comment: @Christ Updated the answer. The location of the .jks is not important. With the gradle script you can define the path. To build with build.gradle you have to tell Gradle the credentials. You can define them in the script or outside.

Comment: The storePassword  and other credentials must be match with the credentiols given while we generate APK right  http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio ?

Comment: So step 1 : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#studio and we should use the credentials given in step 1 to   step 2 : http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html#release-mode right ?

Comment: Yes, the credentials have to match the same used while generating the keystore file.

Comment: Oki..thank you very much for your time and the great explanations.