# Google-map work on emulator but doesn't on real device

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

I applied the exact steps as mentioned in the [google developer doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/start#get-key) to create an example google map project and everything went fine on the emulator, but when I generated the project apk file and launched it on real device Samsung Galaxy S4 google map doesn't show up it shows only a blank background with just colored Google logo appearing on the left lower screen corner !!

What could be the problem? Plz Help.

Comment: hope your net connection is fine

Comment: Did you generated signed APK ?

Comment: net connection is fine

Comment: Yes – Anoop I generated a signed APK file

Answer (score 0):

It is working on emulator on debug mode because you are using the Google Map Api key which is register with your debug.keystore file. To access Google Map into the real device you have to generate the Google Map key using the keystore file which you are using to generate the apk file.

Comment: Ok nice how will I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you installed **Google Setting** App on your mobile.

[image: google settings]

Check this 
[image]

Comment: Not sure I think not, how to do that?

Comment: check this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3410475/how-to-detect-an-android-device-whether-it-s%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8Bupports-google-maps-api

Answer (score 0):

You will get `.keystore` or `.jks` file while generating signed APK.In fact using that you have to create the finger print for your application which is later used to generate Android Key in [Google developer console](https://console.developers.google.com/project).

Now what you have to do is use the command to generate the SHA-1 certificate fingerprint

```
 keytool -list -v -keystore "path_to_jks_file.jks" -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

In that `path_to_jks_file.jks` you should give the path of your `.jks` file that you got when generating signed APK.

And get your android key from google developer console then add it in manifest

[image]

And remember to add the signing configuration to your `build.gradle`

```
signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("myreleasekey.jks")
            storePassword "password"
            keyAlias "MyReleaseKey"
            keyPassword "password"
        }
    }
```

[Signing your application](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

[Visit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645835/confused-with-signing-android-apk) for clarification.

An elaborated explanations [Signup and API Keys](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup)

AFAIK these information's good enough for resolving your issue.tell me if any further.

Comment: I created new project for google map I created new .jks file for the project and created store and key pass and alias then I extracted the SHA1 from cmd java bin I went to dev.google.com/console created new project then enabled google maps android API then created API key from Credentials pasted this API key in place in google_maps_api.xml in my project  updated the signingConfigs release with the .jks file path and alias and two passwords. then generated signed APK from Android Studio then transferred the app-release.apk to real device then installed it same problem google map NOT showing

Answer (score 0):

It's important to remember that Build Releases **debug and release** mode often have different (.xml) values file.
if you are using a Linked Resource File (eg: Google_maps_api.xml) to manage your Maps Api Key, you need to update both files with their appropriate keys.

Keys must be signed using the same procedure as described above ( using your .jks keystore file ..etc )