# Map not show in map fragment after generated signed apk (debug and release) but show when connected through data cable

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

I generated debug api key on Windows like this :

c:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_09\bin>keytool.exe -list -v -keystore "c:\Users\MyUsername.android\debug.keystore" -alias androiddebugkey - storepass android - keypass android

after that I register SHA1 to Google Map APIs console, and I get Google Map API key.

I put everthing to androidmanifest.xml, to the point...It is already show the map on map fragment when I debug use data cable to android device. But when I generated signed apk (debug and release) the app did not show map on fragment (it is a blank map).

How to correct this issue? I mean how to show the map when generated signed apk?

Comment: did you register the sha1 from the signed keystore to google map api?

Comment: already register sha1 to google map api

Comment: Try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33688839/google-map-work-on-emulator-but-doesnt-on-real-device/33691443#33691443

Comment: try that 3 solutions, not work for me.Help...