# Google Maps blank on real Android device - but works on Emulator

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

---

Hola,

I am trying to get the maps to work, it appears to work fine the the Nexus 6 emulator, however when I run it on a Moto G or a Samsung Galaxy the map is completely bank - it just contains the google logo in the bottom corner.

I have generated a google maps key and put that in my google_maps_api.xml file. Do I have to generate a SHA-1 certificate fingerprint?
If yes, how do I do this?

See answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33691443/5387193
I don't quite understand the instructions.

Here is my log:
http://textuploader.com/52xzy

Edit 1:
Added line to AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

It is now working on my Moto G but not on my Samsung. I think because I haven't accepted the sensitive information permission (ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION).

This app I am working on does not need to know the GPS location of the user, so I don't really need this sensitive information - is there an easy way to remove this function and permission?

I think the permission is causing the problems.

Edit 2:
I have got the code:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
    android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />
```

in my AndroidManifest.xml, the `@string/google_maps_key` is a correct key that I have generated. I have generated a SHA1 fingerprint to get the key, do I need to put the fingerprint in my code somewhere?

I haven't generated a release key, I think it is just a debug key. Do you think this might be the issue?

I will setup google play services and see how that affects it.

Edit #3:
Uninstalled and reinstalled Google Play Services on Samsung and now it is working.

Comment: Any chance you can reformat those logs as code so it's actually readable with linebreaks?

Answer (score 2):

This line in your logcat seems to be the problems:

```
02-23 10:02:01.591 5760-5760/com.companyperth.companytools E/GMPM: GoogleService failed to initialize, status: 10, Missing an expected resource: 'R.string.google_app_id' for initializing Google services.  Possible causes are missing google-services.json or com.google.gms.google-services gradle plugin.
```

It looks like Google Play services is not properly setup. You need to get `google-services.json` and put it into your project. To set up Google Play Services correctly, see [Google APIs for Android](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup).

You need to generate SHA1 fingerprint in order to get the Android key if you are using Google Maps for Android. See [Get API key - Google Maps for Android](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/signup). However, if you are using the Google Maps Javascript API(integrated into Android) you will not need to generate SHA1 fingerprint as you will be using Server Key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your google map. I think that is the issue.