# Maps don't show in signed android app using V2 (full apk signature)!

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, android-maps

I know that this question is a duplicate to the one in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35567666/google-maps-blank-on-real-android-device-but-works-on-emulator), But no one gave the right answer to that question till now, so I am asking it again:
I created an app. I used the map activity offered by Android Studio templates. I created a new key to sign the app. I created api using the package name and fingerprint (SHA1) of the app.  Then I made sure that I have an api key  in the release version of google_maps_api.xml file. Then I generated signed APK using V2 (full apk signature), but the map is not showing in the signed apk when I install it on a real device. The map show only in the emulator or on a real device in debug mode, but never shows when I install the signed version of the app!!!
Any help?

Comment: sha key for map need to be generated using signed key in signed apk

Comment: steps please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a Release key with your keystore file and password for `Signed Apk`

Then u have to add the key in developer console

**Step 1**

in command prompt:

```
keytool -list -v -keystore /home/rafsan/Desktop/Android/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks -alias test -storepass password -keypass password
```

where

`/home/rafsan/Desktop/Android/Projects/TestApp/keystore.jks` is the path where your keystore file for the signed apk is present

`test` is the key alias name used while genrating the signed key store

and `password` is the password used while signing the apk

**Step 2**

Go to [Developer console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/)

and add the release key with package

```
A3:33:EA:3D:5E:....................85;com.example.package_name
```

Comment: I tries to execute this command, but it is not recognized as a command!

Comment: Go to this directory in command prompt: `C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\bin` and execute the command...main idea is to go to your Java jre installation folder

Comment: I did as exactly as you wrote, with the same result: 'keytool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Edit: I did it again and it worked. Which one should I use with the package name, the MD5, the SHA1 or the SHA256 to generate api for the release version of the app?