# Android Studio: How to generate multiple APKs or signed APKs for all productFlavors at once for a selected buildType?

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, apk, build.gradle, android-productflavors

I want to make all apk files for release to all stores, so I have to use a `productFlavor` for each apk:

**build.gradle**

```
buildTypes {
        release {
           ...
        }
        debug {
           ...
        }
    }

    productFlavors {
        red {
           ...
        }
        yellow {
           ...
        }
    }
```

**outputs**

```
appname_red_debug.apk
appname_red_release.apk
appname_yellow_debug.apk
appname_yellow_release.apk
```

and I know above codes can change apk's file name. But when I generate the signed apk, I have to choose only one `productFlavor`. This way, the result is only specific to that `productFlavor`.

: **UPDATED**

How can I make all apk files at once on commend line using assembleRelease? Is there anyone who knows about this?

Comment: you should use gradle wrapper to assembleRelease and get all apk at the same time.

Comment: hold on ! okay ! let me try it

Comment: nothing so complicated required. Android Studio supports it by default. If you can see the list you can select it. Check my answer below.

Comment: that's awsome ~ :D I never thought I can select many options lolll thank you so much but I want to know how it works on commend line as well

Comment: @KimKevin not sure if you were sarcastic in the comment above but, if it helped I'm glad. :-) Btw, what do you mean by commended line? can you elaborate?

Comment: @Virus I want to make apk files on command line, I mean script. so any idea for assembleRelease? do u know any options to set productFlavor in with "./gradlew assembleRelease"

Comment: never tried that sorry, but now I'm curious to know. If you find out do leave a comment here. If i find I will too.

Comment: @Virus Of course I will do it ~ u will see it. thank you for sharing ur awesome answer.

Comment: @Virus got answer now ! see that ~

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can always select multiple flavors from the list when generating signed apk after selecting build type. It will generate apks for all selected flavors for the given build type. I've done this several times.

**How, you ask?** Select one flavor and press **Ctrl + A** to select all flavors or **Press Ctrl and select multiple flavors** as you want.

Here is an screenshot of me doing it right now (flavor names masked):

[image]

**Update:** *I explored a bit more and noticed that **dragging mouse to select multiple items doesn't work here** as in other tools. This is the reason for all the confusion and I think Google should enable selection that way otherwise the feature may remain unused by many users.*

Comment: I did the same and generated multiple apks from this window and when uploaded to play store it says that it is signed with a different certificate. All of my flavors have a different keystore file. Can you help?

Answer (score 9):

If you would like to use the command line you can use one of these commands:

```
 All buildVariants
 - ./gradlew assemble

 All flavors for a buildType
 - ./gradlew assembleDebug
 - ./gradlew assembleRelase

 All buildTypes for a flavor
 - ./gradlew assembleRed
 - ./gradlew assembleYellow

 Only a buildVariant
- ./gradlew assembleRedDebug
- ./gradlew assembleRedRelease    
- ./gradlew assembleYellowDebug
- ./gradlew assembleYellowRelease
```

Also you can change the apk name using

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "....");
```

For example

```
project.ext.set("archivesBaseName", "myApp."+ defaultConfig.versionName);
```

Comment: this is what I want, and I just found other way but I love it. thank you so much!

Comment: Nice, but won't the signing configs need to be preconfigured for this to generate signed apks? Just curious add I've never tried

Comment: @Virus You can configure the signing config in your build.gradle script.
For example check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33645835/confused-with-signing-android-apk/33646119#33646119 or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24263715/android-gradle-load-signing-config-from-external-file/24264879#24264879